# Shading sub Layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, fade

I am stuck in a condition that I can't keep the sub layout faded after using the fade animation

```
FrameLayout mapLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mapLayout);

Animation fadeAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
mapLayout.startAnimation(fadeAnim);
```

Please guide how can I achieve this in android. This animation and shaded effect occurs when I click the 'Pause' Button and to reverse the effect I will press the 'Resume' Button(Sorry I made the image with 'Pause' button in shaded view, in actual it is 'Resume')

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both above answers helped me in solving the issue, but both answers weren't the actual solution to my problem. The solution I made is

I defined two animations according to my need

```
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(0f,0.5f);
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f,1f);
fadeOut.setFillAfter(true);
fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);
```

When I clicked 'Pause' button I executed following line

```
mapLayout.startAnimation(fadeOut);
```

Then to resume from paused state, I executed following line

```
mapLayout.startAnimation(fadeIn);
```

Thanks Simon and Deepak!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fadeAnim.fillAfter(true);
fadeAnim.execute();
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks Simon, for your quick response. it worked but it just blacked out all. I need shaded black.. so that previous layout is a bit visible.

Answer (score 0):

hii makki you can set the below code at your onclick event

```
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(50);
set.addAnimation(animation);

animation = new TranslateAnimation(
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
);
animation.setDuration(100);
set.addAnimation(animation);

LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
l.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

then fade out animation

```
 public static Animation runFadeOutAnimationOn(Activity ctx, View target) {
  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,android.R.anim.fade_out);
  target.startAnimation(animation);
  return animation;
}
```